# AggregateFluent and aggregate query

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb

I have the following aggregate query

```
aggregate(
[{"$facet": 
    {"home": [{"$match": {"$expr": {"$eq": ["$IsHomePage", true]}}}],
      "notHome": 
      [{"$match": 
          {"$expr": 
            {"$and": 
              [{"$ne": ["$IsHomePage", true]}, {"$eq": ["$IsTagged", true]}]}}},
        {"$sample": {"size": 50}}]}},
  {"$project": {"union": {"$concatArrays": ["$home", "$notHome"]}}},
  {"$unwind": {"path": "$union"}},
  {"$replaceRoot": {"newRoot": "$union"}}])
```

is it possible to store this code in the variable and than reference it from the `AggregateFluent`

```
return await db.posts.Aggregate<Post>(VARIABLE_NAME).ToListAsync();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly, `Aggregate` supports `PipelineDefinition` as input argument which accepts each stage separately like:

```
  var pipeline = PipelineDefinition<Post, Post>.Create(
            "{ <aggregate stage1> }",
            "{ <aggregate stage2> }");
```

if you want to use the syntax that you mentioned above, you should use:

```
  var coll = db.GetCollection<Post>("coll")
            .Aggregate<Post>()
            .AppendStage<Post>("{ <stage1> }")
            .AppendStage<Post>("{ <stage2> }");
```

to create PipelineDefinition, you also can use EmptyPipelineDefinition:

```
  var pipelineDefinition = new EmptyPipelineDefinition<Post>()
            .AppendStage<Post, Post, Post>("{ <stage1> }")
            .AppendStage<Post, Post, Post>("{ <stage2> }");
```

also, pay attention that you can use a builder for facet itself for example:

```
   var pipeline = PipelineDefinition<BsonDocument, BsonDocument>.Create(
            "{ $unwind : \"$tags\" }",
            "{ $sortByCount : \"$tags\" }");
   var facet = AggregateFacet.Create("name", pipeline);

   var result = subject.Facet(facet);
```

Comment: what is the subject here? In subject.Facet(facet);

Comment: `collection.Aggregate().Facet(..)`